# Bridge Rectifier's Output Became Near-Zero Value After The Implementation of a Voltage Divider

Tags: transformer, voltage-divider, bridge-rectifier

Weird. I have both simulated (shown in picture) and practical circuit built. Simulation works as expected.

On the practical circuit, the output of the full-wave bridge rectifier gives the result similar to simulation. But after implementing a voltage divider (in order to scale-down the rectifier's output voltage of 7.3V to 4V for microcontroller to read) at the rectifier's output, the output of the voltage divider (as well as the output of the rectifier) gives a value near-zero (millivolts range). Any idea what happen to my practical circuit?[image]

(As you can see, the simulated circuit is working as expected, 7.3V can be scaled-down to 4V. But not sure what's the reason of the practical circuit being brought down to approx. 0V after implementing the voltage divider...)

(Transformer: Scales down 230Vrms to 6Vrms;
FW Bridge Rectifier: Convert sine AC to pulsating DC;
Voltage Divider: Further scale-down voltage to 4V)

Comment: In the simulator it is shown that you get what you expect so the circuit is OK. Is your physical circuit exactly the same? Did you double-check? How do you measure the output voltage?

Comment: Is the MCU pin accidentally an output instead of an input? Are the resistor values in your circuit correct and connected properly?

Comment: It all depends what else you have connected to V0_output(1). Look for some low impedance to GND on the board that isn't in your simulation.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes I did double-check. I measured the output using:
- True RMS multimeter: Red probe on the VD_output, black probe on the other leg of the 10k resistor.
- Oscilloscope: Main probe on VD_output, side black mini probe on the other leg of the 10k resistor.

Comment: @Justme no MCU pin is connected yet. Just testing the transformer, bridge rectifier and the voltage divider alone just like how it is connected in the picture provided.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have tried to hook up VD_output with a 3.3k resistor that is connected to GND. But I will try replacing with a much lower resistance tomorrow and see how's the result. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: With 3.3K in parallel with R8 you should get about 1/4 of the voltage you want. A lower resistor will give you even less. Put whatever resistor you choose on the simulation. (I would choose infinity, leaving just R8)

Comment: @BrianDrummond noted. Will update here on the results I get tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the problem on my practical circuit. CONTINUITY problem.

I've used jumpers and crocodile clips to connect from source to components. Jumper wires are fine. But this is the first time that I've found out there's also continuity problem in crocodile clips as well. After replacing and testing all the wires' continuity, the oscilloscope waveform shown is the same as the waveform shown in the simulation (picture).

Proteus Simulation of the Scaled-down Rectified Output:
[image: Proteus Simulation of the scaled-down rectified output]

Practical Oscilloscope Waveform of the Scaled-down Rectified Output:
[image: Practical output waveform of the scaled-down rectified output via Oscilloscope]